# flutter on click function for individual Drawer option

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

import 'package:buggy/theme/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
Widget listTile({IconData? icon, String? title}){
return InkWell(
onTap: () {

```
  },
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(
      icon,
      size: 32,
    ),
    title: Text(title!, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
  ),
);
```

```
}@overrideWidget build(BuildContext context) {return Drawer(child: Container(color: MyTheme.lightBluishColor,child: ListView(children: [DrawerHeader(child: Row(children: [CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: MyTheme.bluishColor,radius: 43,child: CircleAvatar(radius: 40,backgroundColor: MyTheme.creamColor,child: Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618641986557-1ecd230959aa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8cHJvZmlsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=60", height: 65,),),),Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: [
```

```
                        Text("Welcome Guest"),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

                          },style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: MyTheme.bluishColor
                          ), child: Text("Login")),
                        )
                      \],
                    ),
                  )
                \],
              ) 
            ),
            listTile(icon: Icons.home_outlined, title: "Home"),
            listTile(icon: Icons.person_outline, title: "Profile"),
            listTile(icon: Icons.notifications_outlined, title: "Notification"),
            listTile(icon: Icons.star_border_outlined, title: "Rating & Review"),
            listTile(icon: Icons.saved_search_sharp, title: "Saved"),
            listTile(icon: Icons.file_copy_outlined, title: "Raise to Complaint"),
            listTile(icon: Icons.format_quote_outlined, title: "FAQs"),
        ],
      ),
    ),

);
```

}
}

this is my Drawer code.
How to Make individual dart file for List Tile like notification, saved, profile etc ???

I want that Each ListTile should be clickable and open a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom widget , I will share an example code

```
tile({String? label = "", VoidCallback? onTap, IconData? iconData}) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ListTile(
          visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -2),
          leading: Icon(iconData!),
          title: Text(label!),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 15),
          onTap: onTap,
        ),
        Divider(thickness: 1, height: 1),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can call this function in your code in place of listTile like

```
tile(
                    label: "Home",
                    iconData: Icons.home_outlined,
                    onTap: () {
                       //here you can write the code of which page to open on OnTap of Home tile
                    }),
tile(
                    label: "Profile",
                    iconData: Icons.person_outline,
                    onTap: () {
                       //here you can write the code of which page to open on OnTap of Profile tile
                    }),
```